# Finding distribution function of a variable

Tags: probability-distributions

Let's say we have a random variable $X$ with uniform distribution from $0$ to $1$, so $X \in U(0,1)$. How can we find a distribution function of some other variable that can be expressed using X, for example: $$Y=\frac{1}{X+1}$$
What is a general procedure of finding distribution functions like that of $Y$?

Comment: Apply the definition of distribution function. Express the distribution function of $Y$ in terms of that of $X$, whose expression you know.

Comment: @StubbornAtom If the probability density function of X is $f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}=1$, is it then for $y$: $f(y)=\frac{1}{f(x)+1}=1/2$?

Comment: No, look up *distributions of functions of random variables* in your textbook/notes or online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x$ gets from $0$ to $1$, $y$ gets from $1/2$ to $1$.
You know that X is uniformly distributed from $0$ to $1$ so you know the functions $f_X(x)$ and $F_X(x)$ 
Now:
$$F_Y(y) = P(Y< y) = P(1/(X+1) < y) = P(X > 1/y - 1) = 1 -P(X < 1/y - 1)=\\=
1 - F_X(1/y - 1)$$ and replace it to $F_X(x)$